# Fixed point library that represent number with more than 128 digits for c++

Tags: c++

I am looking for a free C++ fixed point library that supports precision more or equal to 252 like as gmp but with fixed point. I need this library to compare and to represent the numbers in Oracle database(NUMBER datatype), therefore I cannot use library Libfixmath.

Do you know some kind of library in c++? Thanks.